# How to get a Media player in firefox fullscreen

Tags: java, android, firefox

I am developing a kinda second screen thing which is nothing more than an Android App sending an code to a Java server which is running on my PC (the target is to run it on a Raspberry Pi in the future, but 1st i want to make it run on my Windows PC).

I have succesfully established a connection between my Android App and the Java Server. I click a button in the app, which sends a code. The Server gets it, calls a method which processes the code and all that works.

By now the main thing is to open my default Browser (Firefox) which a specified URL (https://www.ran.de/us-sport/nfl/live) and what i want to do is, to get the thing on fullscreen.

The HTML Code for the fullscreen button looks like this:

```
<div class="k-table-cell k-button k-fullscreen-toggle-button k-89lf02g">
<div class="k-icon k-icon-fullscreen">::after</div> </div>
```

To this time the player doesnt start automatic, but this is not a problem, since i only need that at the weekends when they air a live stream which will then start automaticlly.

So the only thing i need is some kind of approach of how i can set the player on fullscreen using my java server.

Comment: This isn't an Android dev. Your webpage in the FireFox browser isn't related to Android specifically. Also, it has to with the CSS/JS of the webpage.